# $A,B,C \in M_n$; $AXB=C$; if $A$ or $B$ singular, a solution $X$ exist iff $\text{rank}\{B^T\otimes A\}=\text{rank}\{B^T\otimes A\,\text{ vec}(C)\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

Let $A,B,C \in M_n$ and the equation $AXB=C$. If either $A$ or $B$ is singular, then a solution $X$ can exist if and only if $\operatorname{rank} \left\{ B^T  \otimes A \right\} = \operatorname{rank} \left\{ B^T  \otimes  A  \operatorname{vec}(C ) \right\}$, where $\otimes$ is a Kronecker product.

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** the key is to note that 
$$
(B^T \otimes A) \operatorname{vec}(X) = \operatorname{vec}(AXB)
$$

Comment: yes, that I agree. Perhaps I should have added this relation. However, my question is how the rank condition ensures that $B^T \otimes A$ can be inverted. I am still missing the connection

Comment: Just because a solution exists, doesn't mean that $B \otimes A$ can be inverted.  The condition ensures that $\operatorname{vec}(C)$ is in the column space of $B^T \otimes A$.

Comment: In fact, it's easy to show that if either $A$ or $B$ is not an invertible square matrix, then $B^T \otimes A$ will **not** be invertible.

Comment: Does this solution $\textrm{vec}(X) = B^{-T} \otimes A^{-1} \textrm{vec}(C)$ make sense when both $A$ and $B$ are nonsingular. Correct?

Comment: Sorry, I was bit slow here. Noticed your comments right now.

Comment: Thank you. I still need to understand why the solution exists, when the $\textrm{vec}(C) \in \textrm{columnspace} (B^T \otimes A)$. Perhaps, it is obvious for you experts. Apologies that I lack the background to comprehend.

Comment: Perhaps you should take a closer look at the definition of the column space.  In particular, the equation $Ax = b$ has a solution if and only if $b$ is in the column space of $A$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate that. I think it was just not clicking to me. now I see.

Comment: last comment/question, promise. So, the solution $\textrm{vec}(X)$ will have a pseudo inverse of the matrix say $D = B^T \otimes A$ when either $A$ or $B$ is singular. Right?

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: I meant that the following solution $\textrm{vec}(X) = D^{\dagger} \textrm{vec}(C)$, where $D= B^T \otimes A$ and $D^{\dagger}$ corresponds to moore-penrose inverse (aka pseudo inverse) of $D$. So, if either $A$ or $B$ is nonsingular but $\textrm{vec}(C) \in \textrm{Columnspace}(D)$ then the solution exist. Does this make sense?

Comment: The Moore Penrose pseudoinverse *always* exists, though. When a solution exists, it produces one such solution. When no solution exists, it produces a least squares best answer.